# DataReader already open error when trying to run two queries

Tags: asp.net, sqldatareader

I have a couple of queries that I need to run one to a linked server and one not like this

```
    Dim InvestorLookup As String = "DECLARE @investor varchar(10), @linkedserver varchar(25), @sql varchar(1000) "
    InvestorLookup += "SELECT @investor = '" & investor & "', @linkedserver = '" & db & "', "
    InvestorLookup += "@sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(' +@linkedserver + ', ''SELECT * FROM db WHERE investor = ' + @investor + ' '')' EXEC(@sql)"
    Dim queryInvestorLookup  As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(InvestorLookup , conn)

    Dim BondNoDR As SqlDataReader = queryInvestorLookup.ExecuteReader()

    Dim PasswordCheck As String = "DECLARE @investor varchar(10), @password varchar(20), @linkedserver varchar(25), @sql varchar(1000) "
    PasswordCheck += "SELECT @investor = '" + investor + "', @password = '" + password + "', @server = '" + db2 + "', "
    PasswordCheck += "@sql = 'SELECT * FROM @server WHERE investor = @investor AND password = ' + @password + ' '' EXEC(@sql)"
    Dim queryPasswordCheck As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(PasswordCheck, conn)

    Dim PasswordDR As SqlDataReader = queryPasswordCheck.ExecuteReader()
```

As far as I can tell from debugging the queries both run as they should but I get the error

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
```

Is it possible to run two queries in two different DataReaders. I need to later reference each DataReader and select values from each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it´s not possible to have two SqlDataReader's open at the same time sharing the same SqlConnection object. You should close the first one (queryInvestorLookup) before calling the second (queryPasswordCheck).

This would be good from a design and performance point of view since a recommendation for .NET is that every unmanaged resource (like database access) is opened as later as possible and closed early as possible.

Another way would be to enable MARS but afaik it is only available for Sql2005 and up.

The third solution would be to use the same SqlDataReader to issue the two queries and then navigate through then using NextResults() method.

Comment: Actually I believe that MARS support was introduced with SQL 2005

Comment: How can I find out which SQL Server i'm on?

Comment: @tucaz I added the `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` bit and it doesn't error which suggests it does support that but i still get the open datareader error as before

Comment: Are you getting the same error? According to this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx) the only thing needed to enable it is to put the info on the connection string (like you did) and you should be good to go. However, I suggest you to take one of the other two approaches I offered in my answer since they will save you some resources.

Answer (score 0):

By default you can't have to dataReaders open on the same connection. So you could get one result, stuff it in a DataTable and then get the other result. Or you could turn on MARS

[ADO.NET Multiple Active Resut Sets](https://web.archive.org/web/20150805155408/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/angelsb/archive/2004/09/07/226597.aspx)

Comment: How can I 'stuff' it into a DataTable?

Comment: You can use the adapter to automatically put a DbDataReader into a DataTable or DataSet. Essentially you create an instance of an adapter and assign it the SelectCommand (the command that you use for your select statement) and then call the Fill method on the adapter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the provider that you are using supports it, you can enable MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets) by adding MultipleActiveResultSets=True to the connection string that you are using.